# Changing branches makes my new files appears only on the old one

Tags: git, branch

I've switched the branch that I was working from 'master' to a 'stable' branch, made my modifications and commited/pushed to that branch. Switched back to 'master' and started to implement a new feature to the software. But when I tried to add my modifications, only the files that was modified or deleted appeared to be added to the repository. The new ones that I've created simply didn't show up!

So I copied all the files to a new location in my computer, switched the branch to the 'stable' again and for my surprise there was my new files! I deleted the files to make sure that no modification was made in that branch, switched back to 'master', copied the files from my backup and no new file appeared.

I've already made this a thousand times, and this was the first time that this happened. I use SourceTree, but for this I've tried the git bash too (which I don't have much knowledge about).

What happened? Why my new files are 'attached' to the 'stable' branch? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

*Update:*
I've made a clone of the same repository in another folder to see if things work, but I had no success. The problem still happens.

Comment: `But when I tried to add my modifications, only the files that was modified or deleted appeared to be added to the repository.` So you are not able to add those files on master branch, even though they exist there?

Comment: Yes, exactly! The files are there, are not in the .gitignore nor in gitignore_global. They are perfectly eligible to be added :)

Something that I noticed on SourceTree now is that the branches are with their colors switched. Normally, the master is blue and the first branch is purple, but here they are inverted.

Comment: Are you sure there is no pattern matching the file names? gitignore can ignore files based on patterns as well, you don't have to specify the exact file name. Also, you can have multiple `.gitignore` files, one within each directory. Do a `find . -iname "*gitignore*"` to check if there are multiple .gitignroe files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, you have modifed, added and committed files on one branch (`stable`) and when you switch to the other branch(`master`), you are not able to find the changes in your `master`  branch.

For resolving that, you need to merge your branch stable into branch master. git tracks changes to tracked files against each branch, and to see changes made to one branch in another branch, you need to explicitly tell it to merge those changes.

Assuming all your code is working code in both the branches and you have already stashed your new changes (using `git stash`), you can merge your stable branch into master branch using

```
git checkout master
git merge stable
```

This might throw in some merge conflicts if you have further worked upon and committed some  common files and your branches have diverged, so you may need to resolve those conflicts manually.

**EDIT**

OP says in his comments that `git add . --force` worked for him.

That means, one of the `.gitignore` pattern on master branch is ignoring all the local changes for master branch. I would suggest comaparing (all) the .gitignore files from both the branches with each other and identify which pattern is causing the issue.

From [git add man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html)

The git add command will not add ignored files by default. If any ignored files were explicitly specified on the command line, git add will fail with a list of ignored files. Ignored files reached by directory recursion or filename globbing performed by Git (quote your globs before the shell) will be silently ignored. The git add command can be used to add ignored files with the -f (force) option.

Comment: At the end was the `gitignore` file!
I tried to add a text file to several folders and saw that only one of them rejected to add it. Removed the `gitignore` file and everything worked again. So I opened the file and saw in the first line:

`bin*/`

And the folder that was ignoring the files was `Bingos`. So I replaced that line with:

`bin/
bin-debug/
bin-release/`

And the case is solved! The weird thing is that it never happens until yesterday... I'm suspecting that it is the `.git/config` file that says `ignorecase = true` but was false in the past.

Comment: Just for the record: I can't merge the two branches. The `stable` one is very old and we just do bug fixes on it. By the way, thanks for your anwer, @ansh0l !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

> git add *fileName*

command from git bash, for all your new files, when you are on master branch.

Comment: I've tried this too, but no file is added or error is shown. Besides, with a `git status`, no new file is listed to be added!

Answer (score 0):

There's a more convenient way to add files to git, if you are using SourceTree. You should simply press the Add or Add/Remove button on the top button bar.

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is not the issue. The files doesn't even appear to be added!